# HDF5 as dynamic linked library Qt/C++ under Windows

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, hdf5

I downloaded

Windows (64-bit)   [1](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html)   Compilers:   CMake VS 2013 C, C++, IVF 15 from [here](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html)

Now I read on their homepage that

1. this contains only release libraries and
2. that there are libararies contained with a lib prefix, and they are static libraries
3. that there are libreries without a lib prefix and they are dynamic libaries

For example hdf5.lib and libhdf5.lib

I would like to link dynamically. On their homepage they say that

> To use the shared libraries on Windows specify the
>   H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB compile definition.

What does this mean??? What do they want me to do in order to use the libraries without prefix for dynamic linbking?

Comment: Call `cmake -DH5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB=true`?!

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who comes across this question and is using Visual Studio, another solution is to open the [project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/working-with-project-properties) and go to **Configuration Properties** ⇒ **C/C++** ⇒ **Preprocessor** and add `H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB` to the list of **Preprocessor Definitions**.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this](http://lists.hdfgroup.org/pipermail/hdf-forum_lists.hdfgroup.org/2012-November/006274.html)....

Add

```
#define H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB 1
```

to H5pubconf.h